# can not pass array value to a click function 

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

i plan to show some images on the page and when the user press up button some related new images will be shown. I have been achieving that by changing the "**src**" attribute already existing image html tag.

i have json data like `[["a","b"],["c","d"]]` which gives the name of images like **a.jpg, b.jpeg** etc.

Here is the problem i can not pass the array value to jquery click object. my javascript functions as below:

```
var a; // a global variable holding the json array [["a","b"],["c","d"]]

function rileri(){ //img next
var ix=parseInt($("#up").attr('rel'));
ix=(ix+1)%a.length; 
for(var i=0;i<2;i+=1){ 
   $("#k"+i).attr("src","img/m/t/"+a[ix][i]+".jpg"); 
   $("#k"+i).click(function() { rgetir(a[ix][i]);}); //problem is here!!
 }
$("#up").attr('rel',ix); // i keep index data of appearing img on "rel"
}

function rgetir(n){ //img down ajax
$("#brc").load("data/rgetir.php", {'name':n});
}
```

I wonder how can i bind click event and if there is any better solutions ?

html is like that (no "src" at start, is it ok ?):

```
<img id="k0"/><img id="k1"/>
<input id="up" rel="0" type="button" onclick="rileri()"  value="Next">
```

Yeap the main problem is passing the multidimensional array value to a function :(

Comment: if you add alert to this "rgetir(a[ix][i]);". What do you get?

Comment: It helps to have descriptive names for functions and variables. At least when you are trying to explain what your code does to people.

Comment: NullUserException ఠ_ఠ   you are right, i need to correct them.

Comment: i tried for alert(rgetir(a[ix][i])); and alert(a[ix][i])  both gives "undefined"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with "multidimensional arrays." It is that you are using `i` inside the assigned click value, and `i` changes with every iteration of the loop. Each assigned click value holds a reference to `i`, so when `rileri` is finished each points to the same value. You need to break the reference, usually done by passing `i` to a function and binding the click in there.

There are many flavors of using a function to break a reference, but since you're using jQuery and iterating an array, we'll use `$.each`:

(what follows is untested but should serve as an example)

```
function rileri(){
  var ix=parseInt($("#up").attr('rel'),10);
  ix=(ix+1)%a.length; 

  $.each(a[ix], function (i) {
    var img_name = this;

    $("#k"+i)
      .attr("src","img/m/t/"+img_name+".jpg")
      .click(function () {
        rgetir(img_name);
      });

      if (i >= 2)
      {
        return false;
      }
  });

  $("#up").attr('rel',ix);
}
```

Comment: that gives me a good vision, but somehow when i click an image it starts a infine loop and crash the IE and no response in Firefox. But it seems like a working code

Comment: @JAAulde 'this' in click binder refers to a html image object. i can not find the reason

Comment: @aliaktas I'm sorry, I forgot to grab a reference to `this` inside the `each` before using it in the bound `click`. I've edited the code sample for you.

Comment: the full solution is this one, however both helped a lot. thank you

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple fiddle that shows your problem

http://jsfiddle.net/MHJx6/

The problem is your ix and i variables are closures, so at the time the event runs they have the wrong values as you can see in this example.

---

I tried to write some code that will do what I think you are trying to do below.  It would be easier if I knew what you were trying to do (use case).  Maybe this is what you want?

```
var a; // a global variable holding the json array [["a","b"],["c","d"]]

function rileri(){ //img next
   $("#k0").click(function() { handleClick(0); });
   $("#k1").click(function() { handleClick(1); });
}


function handleClick(index) {
  var ix=parseInt($("#up").attr('rel'));
  ix=(ix+1)%a.length; 

  $("#k"+index).attr("src","img/m/t/"+a[ix][index]+".jpg"); 

  $("#up").attr('rel',ix); 

}
```

Comment: the code is same however a[newImageIndex][index] should be imageArray[newImageIndex][index].  I thought that the code is very short and used the comments to explain what the function's purpose, however you both right in general

Comment: i saw data() functions on fb page, i will try to use it.

Comment: i need to bind a click event, the above code triggers the click and immediately call rgetir()

Comment: when i put a constant in rgetir(), it works but with an array element, no way!. finally i saw some sources mentionin about passing values or references problem, but i am not a coder guru. i am unable to solve the case

Comment: +1 you changed your answer to point to the correct problem as I was typing my answer.